# How do I add a column for each repeated element in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group all costs for each client in a report separated in columns. The number of columns added depends on how many times the same client adds a cost.
For example:

| Client | Costs |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 5 |
| A | 4 |

The result that I want:

| Client | Cost_1 | Cost_2 | Cost_3 | Cost_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| B | 10 | 2 | 5 |  |

Keep in mind the original database is huge so any efficiency would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the serial number of column `Cost`. Then use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to transform the data into columns. Use [`.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) together with the serial number of columns to format the column labels.

```
df['cost_num'] = df.groupby('Client').cumcount() + 1

(df.pivot('Client', 'cost_num', 'Costs')
   .add_prefix('Cost_')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
  Client  Cost_1  Cost_2  Cost_3
0      A     5.0     4.0     NaN
1      B    10.0     2.0     5.0
```

### System Performance

1. Let's see the system performance for 500,000 rows:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit

df2['cost_num'] = df2.groupby('Client').cumcount() + 1

(df2.pivot('Client', 'cost_num', 'Costs')
   .add_prefix('Cost_')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)

587 ms ± 26.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**It takes 0.587 second to run 500,000 rows of dataframe.**

2. Let's see the system performance for 5,000,000 rows:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit

df3['cost_num'] = df3.groupby('Client').cumcount() + 1

(df3.pivot('Client', 'cost_num', 'Costs')
   .add_prefix('Cost_')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)

6.35 s ± 128 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**It takes 6.35 seconds to run 5,000,000 rows of dataframe.**

Comment: Do you think there's a performance cost to `pivot` on a large dataframe?

Comment: @suvayu  We are using all Pandas vectorized operations which have been optimized to run fast rather than using e.g. apply() and lambda function which are just slow Python looping under the hood.  The system performance should be reasonable fast.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because `pivot` reshapes the data.  As far as I understand pandas, internally it uses the `BlockManager`, which groups similar types of data types into contiguous blocks, so I thought, maybe reshaping leads to lots of memory reallocation.  Would be nice to test this with random data.  Just wondering ...

Comment: @suvayu  I've benchmarked the performance of 500,000 rows dataframe, it takes around 0.5 second.

Comment: Ah cool, so I'm over thinking this then :)

Comment: @suvayu  Thanks to the optimization of Pandas by C or CPython codes for vectorized functions that we get much faster performance than native Python codes.   :-)

Comment: Thank you! It really helped.